# What is user agent Issbot

Tags: web-crawlers, user-agent

I am seeing a lot of traffic to my website from user agent Issbot.  This certainly looks like a bot, but is not listed in the www.user-agents.org listing, and I have not been able to find anything useful on Google.  Does anyone know what or who this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did a bit of research. It is apparently a bot owned by these folks: http://www.aloe-systems.com/products (Whois on their ip)

Don't know what it does, except that it ignores your robot.txt file. If I had to guess, it has something to do with that Lawful Interception stuff.